# Mystery Parameter in setState, why does it work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

Going through a TypeScript + React course and building a todo list. My question is about a react feature though.

In the handler for adding a Todo, there is this function declared in setState

```
const App: React.FC= () => {

  const [todos, setTodos] = useState<Todo[]>([])

  const todoAddHandler = (text: string) => {
    // when its called.... where does the prevTodos state come from?
    setTodos(prevTodos => [...prevTodos, 
      {id: Math.random().toString(), text: text}])
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NewTodo onAddTodo={todoAddHandler}/>
      <TodoList items={todos}></TodoList>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When the function is called in setState, it automatically calls the current state with it. Is this just a feature of setState? That if you declare a function within it the parameter will always be the current state when the function is called?

Was very confused when this parameter just... worked. :#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR Is this just a feature of setState? - Yes

> `useState` is a new way to use the exact same capabilities that this.state provides in a class

Meaning that its core still relies on old `this.setState({})` functionality. If you remember using `this.setState()`, you will know that it has a callback function available, which can be used like this:

```
this.setState((currentState) => { /* do something with current state */ })
```

This has now been transfered to `useState` hook's second destructured item `[item, setItem]` **setItem**, thus it has the same capability:

`setItem((currentState) => { /* do something with current state */ })`

You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Comment: Great! Never learned class components, pretty new to react. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With hooks, React contains an internal mapping of each state name to its current value. With

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState<Todo[]>([])
```

Whenever `setTodos` is called and `todos` state is set again, React will update the internal state for `todos` to the new value. It will also return the current internal state for a variable when `useState` is called.

You could think of it a bit like this:

```
// React internals
let internalState;
const setState = (param) => {
  if (typeof param !== 'function') {
    internalState = param;
  } else {
    param(internalState);
  }
};
const useState = initialValue => {
  internalState ??= initialValue;
  return [internalState, setState];
}
```

Then, when you call the state setter, you can either pass it a plain value (updating `internalState`), or you can pass it a function that, when invoked, is passed the current internal state as the first parameter.

Note that the `prevTodos` parameter will contain the current state *including intermediate updates*. Eg, if you call `setTodos` twice synchronously before a re-render occurs, you'll need to use the callback form the second time in order to "see" the changes done by the first call of `setTodos`.